# Using JS to resize an element inside a slide once a slider moves to the next slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

## **SOLVED SOLVED SOLVED SOLVED SOLVED**

I'm learning **JavaScript** while making my own website. I'm using **WordPress** and the plugin **Smart Slider 3** for my main images. The website is still on localhost, unfortunately, so I can't share a URL yet.

One of the elements in the second slide is mispositioned/has the wrong size until the window is resized. I found this tutorial on the plugin's website explaining why and showing how to trigger the resizing manually:

https://smartslider.helpscoutdocs.com/article/1962-trigger-the-resizing-manually

This is the code they provide:

```
_N2.r('#n2-ss-10', function(){
    _N2['#n2-ss-10'].responsive.doResize();
});
```

Unfortunately the developers of the plugin explicitly say they don't provide coding help.

I am still a noob at JS but tried using the code below, **already adapted to use the correct ID** (the CSS selector seems to be correct and is for the "next" button), which I tried adding both to the head and body using **CodeSnippets**, to no avail:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.querySelector('.n2-bullet.n2-style-1b63db3aa0abdb8edd4ab4e9709ae8df-dot.n2-active').addEventListener('click', function(){
    _N2['#n2-ss-2'].responsive.doResize();
    });
});
```

But I keep getting this error in the console:

> ?code-snippets-js-snippets=head&ver=4:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
> at HTMLDocument. (?code-snippets-js-snippets=head&ver=4:1:149)

What am I doing wrong?

**More importantly, I can also change the slides by clicking and dragging the image**. How can I manually call the resize function so that my element is always properly positioned independently of the manner in which I change slides?

Answer (score 0):

After trying an infinite number of things for 6 hours, it finally worked by adding an event listener to clicks on the main container:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const parent = document.querySelector('#post-7105 > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-98227ea.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > ss3-force-full-width');
    if (target.matches('#post-7105 > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-98227ea.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > ss3-force-full-width') || parent.contains(target)) {
        console.log("Clicked inside specified element!");
        _N2['#n2-ss-2'].responsive.doResize();
    }
});
```